# Can we replace all values of column with Row numbers?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

i have a query

```
select name,name_order from name_table where dept_id=XXX;
```

and the resultSet is

```
+------------+--------+
| name_order | name   |
+------------+--------+
|    0       | One    |
|    1       | Two    |
|    2       | Three  |
|    3       | four   |
|    6       | five   |
|    9       | six    |
+------------+--------+
```

i have to update the name_order for the dept_id, in such a way that they start from 0 and
incremented (for that dept_id only)
note : name_order is not an index
the out come should be like

```
+------------+--------+
| name_order | name   |
+------------+--------+
|    0       | One    |
|    1       | Two    |
|    2       | Three  |
|    3       | four   |
|    4       | five   |
|    5       | six    |
+------------+--------+
```

i tried analytical function rowNumber(), it did not help

```
update name_table set name_order = (
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dept_id ORDER BY name_order)-1
)
where dept_id=XXX order by name_order
```

Thanks in advance
-R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE NAME_TABLE A
SET NAME_ORDER=(
  SELECT R 
  FROM (SELECT NAME,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME_ORDER) R
               FROM NAME_TABLE ) B
  WHERE A.NAME=B.NAME);
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6804a/1

```
UPDATE NAME_TABLE A
SET NAME_ORDER=(
  SELECT R 
  FROM (SELECT NAME,DEPT_ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DEPT_ID ORDER BY NAME_ORDER)-1 R
               FROM NAME_TABLE ) B
  WHERE A.NAME=B.NAME AND A.DEPT_ID=B.DEPT_ID /*AND A.DEPT_ID=XXX*/ );
```

Add the condition about dept_id.  Thanks Passerby.

Comment: @Passerby Yes,I didn't consider the dept_id.I update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a `merge command`

```
MERGE INTO name_table dst
USING (SELECT t.*, row_number() over (partition BY dept_id ORDER BY name_order) -1 n
       FROM name_table t) src
ON (dst.dept_id = src.dept_id AND dst.name = src.name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Dst.name_order = src.n;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb0fb/3)

But why would you want a column with values you can have in a query ?

Comment: he could use it as an arbitrary sorting key for UI output of this data, which could be initialized this way and changed later.

Comment: actually, i am using these column values as index(but its not actual index) to sort in JPA many to many relation, which leading to null objects for missing name_order

Comment: though we had a fix at java side, to fix the corrupted data in database i would like to resurrect the column values

Comment: @org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn(name = "NAME_ORDER") is considering the NAME_ORDER as index and causing null objects at UI

Comment: @ranadheermachineni, I still don't understand why you need this. If it's just a key then why do you care if it has gaps or not ? if it's for UI then it should be in UI side or (not sure that even in sql...)

Comment: yes, we fixed UI by adding Null check,finding ways to keep the NAME_ORDER values in ASC order

Comment: i have other object, which has OneToMany relations to the NAME objects. so the getter method is returning nulls in list for rows missing the NAME_ORDER

Answer (score -3):

```
SET @rownum:=0; SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS name_order, names from name_table where dept_id=XXX;

working fine on mysql.
```

Comment: That's not even valid syntax for Oracle.

Comment: thanks sameer. i get following when i run at oracle, line 26: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: